# Repetition of header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please see below example of HTML structure

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
  <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header</h1></div> 

  <div  data-role="content">
      <a href="#" id="add" data-role="button">Click Me</a>
  </div> 

  <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div> 
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="p2"> 
  <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header 1</h1></div> 

  <div  data-role="content">
    Page Two
  </div> 
  <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div> 
</div>
```

jquery for same

```
$('#p1').live('pagecreate', function(e){
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
      $.mobile.changePage('#p2', { transition: "flip"} );
  });
});
```

The above example is working fine but header part is repeating.
So how to avoid this issue because I am using same header as well as footer part for each data-role="page"?

Comment: please note heading numbers should always appear in order so unless your content section contains headings 2 and 3 just before the footer section (and your heading 4 in the footer is part of the last bit of the header 3 content), your site is will fail [w3c validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G141)

Comment: what do you mean by _repeating_?

Comment: Repeating implies I am using same layout and content of header every time. I don't want to repeat header everytime. Is ther any concrete solution?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no nice "built-in" method to do it. You can find some workarounds here: [jQuery Mobile: Use same header footer for all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620692/jquery-mobile-use-same-header-footer-for-all-pages)