# Use the same header/footer in all jQuery Mobile pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web application that uses jQuery Mobile and JSONP requests to update the content. One of the project requirements is that could not have a server-side web language since the goal is to use PhoneGap in order to build a web application.

Since I can't use a server side method such as `include`, I'm thinking in loading the content of the HTML pages via AJAX to `data-role="content"` in order to use the same header/footer in all pages without duplicating the code or generating him through JavaScript. The problem with this approach is that I lose access of some cool jQuery Mobile features, such as elements auto initialization, page transitions, back/forward browser buttons, etc.

What is the best way to use the same header/footer in all jQuery Mobile pages through JavaScript?

Comment: Can't you utilize the server-side of things to reuse your code?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152446/creating-templated-persistant-header-footer-template-in-jquery-mobile-and-phoneg/9204896#9204896

Comment: @KrisKrause no, sorry I forgot to mention that. I've already updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

well you can send from web service footer,header, and content for every page, and update pages.In this way you can also dynamically change links in (header/footer)navigation bar (e.g. depending if user is logged in or not.  )

You can use **pagebeforeshow** event to update HTML
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function (event, data) {
//
});