# How to pass a django variable from html page to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

My website has a sidebar that is the same on all pages.  In order to avoid copying and pasting the html for the sidebar for every page I wrote some javascript as this answer suggested: [How can I make my navi-bar the same across my html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445430/how-can-i-make-my-navi-bar-the-same-across-my-html)

I am happy with these results except for one thing, my sidebar displays things like the users name, which I access with `{{ request.user.get_full_name }}`, but this does not work when I put that in my `sidebar.js`.  So I thought a good work around would be to set a `var user={{request.user.get_full_name}}` in the `<script>` tags in my html file and then use `<h3>user</h3>` in my js, but I am not sure how to do that.

This is my `sidebar.js`

```
document.getElementById("navMenu").innerHTML =
  '<a href="/profile/" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;"><div id="circle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div><h3>Your Name</h3></a>'+
  '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="text-align: left;">'+
    '<li><a href="/userhome/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Home</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="/profile/"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Profile</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Messages</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="/boards/"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Boards</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Feed</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Notifications</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="#"><label for="logout" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: inherit;"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Logout</label></a></li>'+
  '</ul>';
```

So in the second line where it has `<h3>Your Name</h3>` I want that to be the user variable.  And this is how I am trying to pass the variable in my HTML page:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <nav id="navMenu"></nav>
  <script src="{% static 'app/js/sidebar.js' %}">var user={{request.user.get_full_name}}</script>
  <!-- logout button/form -->
  <form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="hidden" id="logout" type="submit" value="Logout"/>
  </form> 
</div>
```

I would like to avoid using PHP.  The bottom line is can I use django like that inside the `<script>` tags and if so, how do I then use that variable in my javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the reference, but I'm skeptical `<script src="something.js">` can also have source within it.  I've not seen it done that I can recall.

This should work, which is similar to what you are doing:

```
<script>
    var user = '{{request.user.get_full_name}}'; // created by your django html 
</script>
<script src="{% static 'app/js/sidebar.js' %}"></script>
```

And then in your `sidebar.js` you just need to do:

```
"....<h3>" + user + "<h3>..."
```

However, a cleaner way to do this would be to encapsulate your js into a function that takes the username as a parameter:

```
<script src="{% static 'app/js/sidebar.js' %}"></script>
```

Where your js is something like,

```
function sidebar(user) {
    document.getElementById("navMenu").innerHTML = "....<h3>" + user + ";<h3>..."
}
```

Followed by:

```
<script>
    sidebar('{{request.user.get_full_name}}'); // where this is created via your template.
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great- I ended up going with your second method and writing it as a function