# load map after the page has entirely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have this js that beginning so:

```
$( "#map-page" ).live( "pageinit", function() 
{
  //Here the body function
});
```

I would load this function after the page has completed to load.how can i do?

Comment: I've seen code before that's suggested using `live('pageinit')` It seems a non-obvious pattern, to me -- where did you get it from?

Comment: I get it from a jquery mobile manual.

Comment: @lonesomeday I have the book: I can't give you the link.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Looks like this method won't work with jQuery mobile (strangely enough).

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#map-page").doWhatever();
})
```

Comment: I think he's referring to jQuery mobile, don't use document.ready for jQuery mobile

Comment: @ClayLiu Thanks, updated to make it more clear. Left the answer because if I didn't, someone else would certainly post it later.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, I think that load suits better

You can read about it here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear that you're referring to jQuery Mobile, anyways the best way is to bind a live event to the pagecreate/pageshow event that's triggered on the `<div data-role="page">`

If you want the code to run just once use pagecreate, if it needs to run everytime the page is shown (there is dynamic data) then use pageshow and fetch any changes via AJAX. Please note if you re-navigate to the page again via the back button etc, it may be fetched from memory in which case your html won't be updated - you must use non-AJAX loading or update your DOM via AJAX in the pageshow

Use an id or class to properly attach the listener, here's a more detailed answer I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085014/737023