# jQuery Mobile Google Maps - Map is only shown after a reload

Tags: jquery, maps

Could someone please have a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have spend so much time now trying out different things but haven't been successful. Tanks to everybody who can help me!

- calling this page directly works
- calling this page from the previous page with link type "external" works
- calling this side normally from one jQueryMobile page to this one, doesn't work and shows the map Empty, after clicking Reload, everything is perfect

The code:

```
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
          <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"  />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="basic_map">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").bind('pageinit', function() {
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                            initialize(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                        });
                }
            });

            function initialize(lat,lng) {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var myOptions = {

                zoom: 12,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

 </script>

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-inset="false">
            <h1>My</h1>
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" >Home</a>
        </div>  

    <div data-role="content">

            <h4>Map</h4>

        <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all " >
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

--edit--
Forget what I said. You are right that it does not solve the problem. :)

It seems you've forgotten to close your initialize() function on line 34! Don't forget to place the doctype  by the way, then it would be line 35.

I see the map right away now on my machine (Chrome 19)

Comment: 1.)i tried to move my existing java script just right before the </body>
--> no change, same issue like before

2.)
I changed the function to start as you described above
in that case even if i reload the page, the map is not shown anymore :-)

i am completely confused and have no idea,....;-)

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer! Thanks by the way for the snippet. I am actually working on a JQM app right now and just needed some info on the user's location. Your example is perfect Now that I've got it working. :D

Comment: i know its working well,....

the close, its a copy error, i have the close in my source

as i said, it works ,nice, except you come from another JQuery page before that

then the java script doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this question turns out to be an exact duplicate of the answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221259/jquery-mobile-not-loading-google-map-except-on-refresh). I'm not sure why it's not working at your side, because I'm using the same code as you now.

I did run into the glitch where my map is off-center, but that was fixed by replacing `pageinit` with `pageshow`. For me reloading the page or even changing my browser's window width fixed it as well.

Is your map entirely invisible, or can you see something in the top-left corner?