# jQuery mobile script requires "hard" reload to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, reload

My script does not work when I load the page using a toolbar. If I click on the link in the toolbar the site opens, but the list view stays empty. When I then do a *hard* refresh, on MacOS like **CMD+R** the list view is filled with content. What am I missing?

```
<script>    
var items = "";
        $.post("../query.php", {action : "someaction"},
        function(data) {
            items = (jQuery.parseJSON(data));
            var $listElem = $('.mylistclass').find('ul');
            $.each(items, function(i, item) {
                $('<li />').append(
                    $('<a />').attr('data-index', i).attr('href', '#').append(
                        $('<img />').attr('src',item.url),
                        $('<h3 />').text(item.title).addClass('ui-li-heading'),
                        $('<p />').text(item.description).addClass('ui-li-desc')
                    )
                ).appendTo($listElem).trigger('create');
            });
            ($listElem).listview('refresh');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: where did you locate this script?? I would execute it on document load

Comment: I just placed it under the standard doc headers. It is strange that in another project this works fine without any additions. But I guess the other project used an older version of jQuery Mobile. Maybe they did change something in their code?

Comment: try wrapping the above code in `$(document).ready(function(ev){ /* The Code */ })`

Comment: Does not help ... Still the same problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the post request doesn't fail?

Comment: "Yes and No". When I do CMD+R the table gets filled with the contents of the JSON Array of the POST request. So the request is alright. It just seems that the site does not "really" load until I do a refresh in my browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15453/discussion-between-davids-and-darwin)

Comment: Question still unsolved.

Comment: Since it's mobile, i would suggest wrapping in a setTimeout with 100ms.

Comment: ... Question _still_ unsolved ...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and the answer to this question was the solution: [Jquery Mobile not loading Google Map (except on refresh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221259/jquery-mobile-not-loading-google-map-except-on-refresh).

To copy Clarence Liu's answer straight: "If you navigate to this page from another page, jQM only pulls in the JS within your div[data-role="page"] tags, so if your JS is in your  tags that won't be pulled in, this is what is causing your issues."