# jQuery mobile dialog popup when index loads

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

After coming from PHP background, I am just trying to get to grips with jquerymobile.

I have created a web app and what I need is a jquery popup with a message on the index page on first load only. I am stuck on

a) How to create the popup to load after page has loaded without intervention

b) Make sure popup only displays on first visit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the pageinit event, bind a handler function and within it show the dialog with

`$.mobile.changePage(url, {role: dialog});`

How you bind the listener for the pageinit event will depend how whether you use IDs etc, one solution is in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085014/737023

Comment: That should be $.mobile.changePage(url, {role: 'dialog'});